# How to write back attributes into the database with abap persistence service?

Tags: persistence, abap

Normally, we have for each attribute of our persistence class a field in the database. Those we can save back by just start a transanction, make some changes and then end our transanction. (like they did [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/de/7c/eb575033e811d5992100508b6b8b11/content.htm))

But now I have a more complex object, going over two tables, (im my case an additional text table), so I add an attribute title, and in the `init( )`I pull the information from the database.

**Now how can I save this information back into the database?** The persistence service does not know where to save that title.

*I did some research and found [this Thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3358250) on SCN, where the root problem (Creating a persistent class for a table with an addidional texttable) is described.*

Comment: Have you tried the [solution](http://scn.sap.com/message/14054327#14054327) from this very thread?

Comment: @vwegert I did not really get how to do the save back to the database. He has them read only.